# Ionic 4 - Select not showing selected value set in controller

Tags: ionic4

**Problem**:

I have an `ion-select` and in the controller when the user does something, I populate the `ion-select` with 1 value and make that value the selected value. The `ion-select` does not show that the value has been selected, but the `[(ngModel)]` has the correct value. When I open the `ion-select` it shows the value in the list and it is selected, when selecting the value in the list again it goes over the `ion-select` `label`.

How can I populate the `ion-select` with a value and make the populated value the selected value so that it shows on the `ion-select` as a selected item?

**Screenshots**:

1. The **Make** has value of **CHEVROLET** but it does not show as selected by `ion-select`:

[image]

2. When tapping on `ion-select`, it shows the **CHEVROLET** as selected and **CHEVROLET** goes over the **Make** `label`:

[image]

**HTML**:

```html
<ion-item>
   <ion-label position="floating">
      <span class="required">* </span>Make
   </ion-label>
   <ion-select [interfaceOptions]="global.compactAlertOptions" id="make" [(ngModel)]="global.valuation.vehicle.make" name="make" #makeRef="ngModel" required>
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let make of makes">{{make}}</ion-select-option>
   </ion-select>
</ion-item>
<ion-label *ngIf="makeRef.touched && makeRef.invalid && makeRef.errors.required" class="error">Make is required</ion-label>
```

**Controller**:

1. Modal Controller (the Make gets set in a popup modal):

> this.global.valuation.vehicle.make = this.vehicleDetails.VehicleMake;

2. Populate the `ion-select` options in parent controller:

> this.makes = [this.global.valuation.vehicle.make];

Answer (score 2):

This generally happens when the value in ngModel is set before `<ion-select-option>` options are loaded on the DOM.

You will have to explicitly delay setting the value to ngModel until the `<ion-select>` and options are loaded on the DOM.

You can achieve it by adding a `setTimeout` in your component file and assign the ngModel value in the callback of setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this has to do with some custom css that you are using on the template. Since when you use floating for a select is exactly the same as when you use stacked, Since the select is going to expand on the ion-item anyway. This floating works best with ion-input.

In your case, if the option was not selected, the select should be empty and the label above it. but it is on the item furthermore on the baseline of the select. When you select the option it will show in the baseline on the select left aligned. 
like this:

[image]

If you remove the floating you will see what I mean. 
it should show like this:

[image]

It will be easier to understand the issue if you just provide the CSS bits that are messing with the alignment of the elements.

My guess is that you have some styles that only reduce the ion-item and don't deal with alignment and positioning of the inner elements.

Comment: I am not using any custom CSS to format the inputs (not that I am aware of). One thing that I noticed since my post, if I bind `this.make` to the input, it works fine, it does not work when binding to `this.global.valuation.vehicle.make`. And also when I manually select the item in the dropdown, it works fine. It only happens when I select the item in the controller

Comment: that's weird, specially if in this case it should not overlap with the Label anyway. You are binding to a var in another component? is it a service? are you sure that after updating that you are keeping the zone?

Comment: Jip it's a shared service. So what I ended up doing is add an `onchange` event on `this.make` `select` dropdown which keeps `this.global.valuation.vehicle.make` in sync with `this.make`. Seems like the binding can't handle so many child properties